# Не могу сделать hover

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, hover

Нужно сделать такой hover:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
<sup>[Ссылка на картинку](http://joxi.ru/4AkzgGxTZWp52q)</sup>

***Задача:*** текст должен появляться плавно, высота *item* должна также плавно увеличиваться и уменьшаться. Блок в котором лежат сами *item'ы* не должен увеличиваться при наведении на *item'ы*.

Помогите плиз, не могу продолжить проект из-за этого.

Comment: Приложите код того, что у вас есть из написанного. Это поможет в решении вашей проблемы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как отправная точка может пригодится для дальнейшего изучения:

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.block {
  width: 20%;
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  transition: height 0.5s ease-out 0.5s, color 0.5s ease-out 0.5s, line-height 0.5s ease-out 0.5s;
}

.block:hover {
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block">BLOCK #1</div>
  <div class="block">BLOCK #2</div>
  <div class="block">BLOCK #3</div>
  <div class="block">BLOCK #4</div>
</div>
```